# For HTML rendered with PHP, which method is faster for putting CSS to such HTML. Including incline CSS or calling a class from the receiving page?

Tags: php, html, css

Consider the following two blocks of code.

1.

```
<?php
$c = 5;
if ($c < 1){
    echo '<span style=" color:#F00;font-size:12px;float:right;">This one is red</span>';
    } else
     echo '<span style=" color:#F00;font-size:12px;float:right;"> C is smaller</span>';
?>
```

2.

```
<?php
$c = 5;
if ($c < 1){
    echo '<span class="classC">This one is red</span>';
    } else
     echo '<span class="classC"> C is smaller</span>';
?>

CSS
     .classC 
      {
       color:#F00;
       font-size:12px;
       float:right;
      }
```

Which one is effective and more correct?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @codehorse, i actually wish StackExchange can created a feature where downvotes are reviewed first, seems like downvotes are just abused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is definitely the preferred way to do this.

The second way is also more effective. They are both technically correct. But it is better to put all your styles in CSS, then to have it stored in html/php files.

Answer (score 3):

Always use CSS Classes. It's better for code reusability.

You should also consider putting your CSS code in an external CSS file. It keeps your HTML code clean, and this way, the browser can cache the CSS file, so it's faster.